# A nicer way to add a new value to string array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have the following code:

```
private void AddMissingValue(ref string[] someArray) {
  string mightbemissing="Another Value";
  if (!someArray.Contains(mightbemissing)) {
    var lst=someArray.ToList();
    lst.Add(mightbemissing);
    someArray=lst.ToArray();
  }
}
```

While this works (Add an item to an array if missing), I wonder if this can be done in a smarter way? I don't like converting the array twice and writing so many lines for such a simple task.

Is there a better way? Maybe using LinQ?

Comment: Can you not just store it as a list and call .ToArray() where you need it in array form?

Comment: Arrays shouldn't be used when you expect the number of elements to change. For that you have other data structures like `List`

Comment: The smart way is to populate your list, and convert it to Array in final step. but that's not necessary either, you can use list most of the times. if you are not limited to library implementations use list.

Comment: also if items in array are always unique you can use hashset, add everything you want to hashset without even looking into it. then finally convert that into array.

Comment: Being an array is a must. It is an external library.

Comment: In fact, it looks like you should be using a `HashSet<string>` and calling `.ToArray()` when necessary.

Comment: Then,as @BugFinder commented, use a list internally and only convert it to array when you need it in the external library

Answer (score 6, accepted):

General idea is right - array is a fixed-sized collection and you cannot add an item to it without recreating an array.

Your method can be written in a slightly more elegant way using LINQ `.Concat` method without creating a `List`:

```
private void AddMissingValue(ref string[] someArray)
{
    string mightbemissing = "Another Value";
    if (!someArray.Contains(mightbemissing))
    { 
        someArray = someArray.Concat(new[] { mightbemissing }).ToArray();
    }
}
```

This implementation takes `N * 2` operations which is better than your `N * 3`, but it is still enumerating it multiple times and is quadratic for adding N items to your array.
If you are going to perform this operation too often, then changing your code to use dynamic-size collections (f.i., `List`) would be a more effective way.

Even if you decide to continue using arrays, it probably *(imo)* will look better if you return modified array instead of using `ref`:

```
private string[] AddMissingValue(string[] someArray)
{
    string mightbemissing = "Another Value";
    return someArray.Contains(mightbemissing)
        ? someArray
        : someArray.Concat(new[] { mightbemissing }).ToArray();
}

// Example usage:

string[] yourInputArray = ...;
yourInputArray = AddMissingValue(yourInputArray);
```

### LINQ-style and the most performant

Another implementation which comes to my mind and is the best (`O(N)`) in terms of performance (not against dynamic-size collections, but against previous solutions) and is LINQ-styled:

```
public static class CollectionExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> AddIfNotExists<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, T value) 
    {
        bool itemExists = false;
        foreach (var item in enumerable)
        {
            if (!itemExists && value.Equals(item))
                itemExists = true;

            yield return item;
        }

        if (!itemExists)
            yield return value;
    }
}

// Example usage:
string[] arr = ...;
arr = arr.AddIfNotExists("Another Value").ToArray();
```

This implementation with `yield` is used to prevent multiple enumeration.

If you need to add multiple items, then it can even be rewritten this way, and it seems to still be linear:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> AddIfNotExists<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, params T[] value) 
{
    HashSet<T> notExistentItems = new HashSet<T>(value);
    foreach (var item in enumerable)
    {
        if (notExistentItems.Contains(item))
            notExistentItems.Remove(item);

        yield return item;
    }

    foreach (var notExistentItem in notExistentItems)
        yield return notExistentItem;
}

// Usage example:
int[] arr = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
arr = arr.AddIfNotExists(2, 3, 4, 5).ToArray(); // 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Comment: side question - is that `ref` neccessary?

Comment: @Toshi Absolutely, yes. If you remove `ref` keyword, then reassigning local `someArray` variable won't affect the original array passed to the method.

Comment: I really like the `yield` solution. But,still, I think the best solution is not using arrays for this... :)

Comment: @Pikoh I totally agree and nearly "forgot" there is something like an array in C# :)  But at the end this ends as a parameter for a method with "params string[] names". So at one point I need to convert the data

Comment: I understand @OleAlbers that you need it. I just say that _the point you need to convert the data_ should be only when you need to pass the parameter to the method ;) `method(namesList.ToArray());`

Answer (score 2):

You have to *resize* the array, see

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051(v=vs.110).aspx

for details. Implementation:

```
// static: it seems that you don't want "this" in the method
private static void AddMissingValue(ref string[] someArray) {
  string mightbemissing = "Another Value";

  if (!someArray.Contains(mightbemissing)) {
    Array.Resize(ref someArray, someArray.Length + 1);

    someArray[someArray.Length - 1] = mightbemissing;
  }
}
```

In you current implementation, you copy all the items **twice** which can be unwanted if the array is *large*

```
...
var lst=someArray.ToList(); // first: all data copied from array to list
lst.Add(mightbemissing);
someArray=lst.ToArray();    // second: all data copied from list to array
```

A better design, however, is to switch from fixed size array `string[]` to, say, `List<string>`:

```
  List<string> someList = ...

  if (!someList.Contains(mightbemissing))
    someList.Add(mightbemissing); // <- just Add
```

if all the values should be not `null` and *unique* you can do further improvement:

```
  HashSet<string> someHash = ...

  someHash.Add(mightbemissing);
```